# DynamoDB Xcode6 Swift using three columns as key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I am trying to use a DynamoDB table to store this data:

DartsPlayerInsultTable

```
CustomerId   String

PlayerId     String

PlayerInsult String
```

Using the method (concept, not code) described here:

```
https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3GYZEVGO924K4/The-DynamoDBMapper-Local-Secondary-Indexes-and-You
```

here:

```
http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxTCW7KW8BGZAF/Amazon-DynamoDB-on-Mobile-Part-4-Local-Secondary-Indexes
```

and here:

```
http://labs.journwe.com/2013/12/15/dynamodb-secondary-indexes/comment-page-1/#comment-116
```

I want to have multiple insult records per customer-player.
    CustomerId is my Hash Key
    PlayerId is my Range Key
and I a trying to use PlayerInsult in a key so that
a second PlayerInsult value inserts a second record
rather than replacing the existing one.

Have tried both Global and Secondary indexes for this,
but if I try to add a row with a new insult, it still 
replaces the insult with the same customer-player key
rather than adding a new one.

Any suggestions on the best approach to use for this is
DynanoDB?  Do I need to create a hybrid column for a range-key?
Trying to keep this simple...

```
class func createDartsPlayerInsultTable() -> BFTask {
    let dynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()

    let hashKeyAttributeDefinition = AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition()
    hashKeyAttributeDefinition.attributeName = "CustomerId"
    hashKeyAttributeDefinition.attributeType = AWSDynamoDBScalarAttributeType.S

    let hashKeySchemaElement = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    hashKeySchemaElement.attributeName = "CustomerId"
    hashKeySchemaElement.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Hash

    let rangeKeyAttributeDefinition = AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition()
    rangeKeyAttributeDefinition.attributeName = "PlayerId"
    rangeKeyAttributeDefinition.attributeType = AWSDynamoDBScalarAttributeType.S

    let rangeKeySchemaElement = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    rangeKeySchemaElement.attributeName = "PlayerId"
    rangeKeySchemaElement.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Range

    /*
    let indexRangeKeyAttributeDefinition = AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition()
    indexRangeKeyAttributeDefinition.attributeName = "PlayerInsult"
    indexRangeKeyAttributeDefinition.attributeType = AWSDynamoDBScalarAttributeType.S

    let rangeKeySchemaElement = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    rangeKeySchemaElement.attributeName = "PlayerId"
    rangeKeySchemaElement.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Range

    let indexRangeKeyElement =  AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    indexRangeKeyElement.attributeName = "PlayerInsult"
    indexRangeKeyElement.keyType = AWSDynamoDBIndexRangeKeyType.
    */

    //Add non-key attributes
    let playerInsultAttrDef = AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition()
    playerInsultAttrDef.attributeName = "PlayerInsult"
    playerInsultAttrDef.attributeType = AWSDynamoDBScalarAttributeType.S

    let provisionedThroughput = AWSDynamoDBProvisionedThroughput()
    provisionedThroughput.readCapacityUnits = 5
    provisionedThroughput.writeCapacityUnits = 5

    // CREATE GLOBAL SECONDARY INDEX
    /*
    let gsi = AWSDynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndex()
    let gsiArray = NSMutableArray()

    let gsiHashKeySchema = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    gsiHashKeySchema.attributeName = "PlayerId"
    gsiHashKeySchema.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Hash

    let gsiRangeKeySchema = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    gsiRangeKeySchema.attributeName = "PlayerInsult"
    gsiRangeKeySchema.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Range

    let gsiProjection = AWSDynamoDBProjection()
    gsiProjection.projectionType = AWSDynamoDBProjectionType.All;

    gsi.keySchema = [gsiHashKeySchema,gsiRangeKeySchema];
    gsi.indexName = "PlayerInsult";
    gsi.projection = gsiProjection;
    gsi.provisionedThroughput = provisionedThroughput;

    gsiArray .addObject(gsi)
    */

    // CREATE LOCAL SECONDARY INDEX

    let lsi = AWSDynamoDBLocalSecondaryIndex()
    let lsiArray = NSMutableArray()

    let lsiHashKeySchema = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    lsiHashKeySchema.attributeName = "CustomerId"
    lsiHashKeySchema.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Hash

    let lsiRangeKeySchema = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    lsiRangeKeySchema.attributeName = "PlayerInsult"
    lsiRangeKeySchema.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Range

    let lsiProjection = AWSDynamoDBProjection()
    lsiProjection.projectionType = AWSDynamoDBProjectionType.All;

    lsi.keySchema = [lsiHashKeySchema,lsiRangeKeySchema];
    lsi.indexName = "PlayerInsult";
    lsi.projection = lsiProjection;
    //lsi.provisionedThroughput = provisionedThroughput;

    lsiArray .addObject(lsi)


    //Create TableInput
    let createTableInput = AWSDynamoDBCreateTableInput()
    createTableInput.tableName = DartsPlayerInsultTableName;
    createTableInput.attributeDefinitions = [hashKeyAttributeDefinition, rangeKeyAttributeDefinition, playerInsultAttrDef]
    //createTableInput.attributeDefinitions = [hashKeyAttributeDefinition, rangeKeyAttributeDefinition]
    createTableInput.keySchema = [hashKeySchemaElement, rangeKeySchemaElement]
    createTableInput.provisionedThroughput = provisionedThroughput
    //createTableInput.globalSecondaryIndexes = gsiArray as [AnyObject]
    createTableInput.localSecondaryIndexes = lsiArray as [AnyObject]

    return dynamoDB.createTable(createTableInput).continueWithSuccessBlock({ (var task:BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if ((task.result) != nil) {
            // Wait for up to 4 minutes until the table becomes ACTIVE.

            let describeTableInput = AWSDynamoDBDescribeTableInput()
            describeTableInput.tableName = DartsPlayerInsultTableName;
            task = dynamoDB.describeTable(describeTableInput)

            for var i = 0; i < 16; i++ {
                task = task.continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task:BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                    let describeTableOutput:AWSDynamoDBDescribeTableOutput = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBDescribeTableOutput
                    let tableStatus = describeTableOutput.table.tableStatus
                    if tableStatus == AWSDynamoDBTableStatus.Active {
                        return task
                    }

                    sleep(15)
                    return dynamoDB .describeTable(describeTableInput)
                })
            }
        }

        return task
    })

}
```

Comment: How long are the insults and how many of them will there be, on average? Could you store the insults as a list in your code and serialize them to a single field? You might still hit the situation where you need to bucket on PlayerId if you break the size limit for a single record.

Comment: Sentences, less than 100.  Keeping them in Dynamo comes with a ready pattern for display/insert/update/delete from an iOS app.  Not sure if there is a simple way to match a  swift table view controller to an array or similar, but I should investigate.  It could simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as an answer and not another comment in case it gets long...

It sounds like the average user's insults might fit into a single record. With the disclaimer that I know absolutely nothing about swift, this might at least be something relatively simple. Keep your customer and player keys. Before you persist the insults, turn the whole list into one big string using whatever version of join("|") swift has. When you fetch the record, do a split("|") to get your list back. (Just be a little judicious with your choice of separators, I'm only using "|" as an example, you don't want to choose something that might appear in an insult...)

There's going to be that *one* user with enough insults to take you over the 400kb object limit. Set a max list size constant in your code -- when you turn your lists into strings to persist them to dynamo, check the player's list length against that limit. If you exceed it, break your list into chunks of that size and use hash and range keys like ("foo", "bar"), ("foo", "bar1"), ("foo", "bar2"), etc. Yes, the first one does *not* have a bucket number at the end...

When you query for the data, just do a straight query first and assume you'll be in the good case (just "foo" and "bar", no other buckets). When you unpack that first list, check its length. If it's equal to your max list size constant, you know that you got a "bad" user and need to do a range query. That second one can use the hash key "foo" and the range "bar" to "bar9999". You will fetch back all those buckets with that range query. Unpack and concatenate all the lists.

This is a little gory, but it should also ultimately be straight ahead to code up. Hopefully it's still simple enough to hook into the patterns you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What I decided to do was make a conventional dynamodb table with just one hash key, but the new hash key is a combined string of:

CustomerId + "|" + PlayerId

It is not too hard to maintain synchrony between players and insults tables because once a player is inserted into the player table, modifying the player name results in a new row being inserted.  Thus, insults do not need to be modified if the player name changes.  You only need to cleanup insults if a player is deleted.

This update behavior is just the way dynamodb works if you make Player name a hash key, which I did to insure they were unique.